# How to create a separate testng-failed.xml for each suite without over-writing?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, testng.xml

I use `mvn test` command to run the suite. My `testng.xml` looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="root-testsuite">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="set-1.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="set-2.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

After the run, the `testng-failed.xml` file that is generated (under `target/surefire-reports` folder) contains only failures from tests that belong to `set-2.xml`. Looks like it creates `testng-failed.xml` for `set-1.xml` but that is over-written after `set-2` gets executed.

How can I create two separate `testng-failed.xml` files like `testng-failed-set-1.xml` and `testng-failed-set-2.xml` to ensure that I have the list of all the failures in the run?

Comment: It's a limitation of testng, I have had the similar issue and it is still open. It always gets overridden

Comment: @cruisepandey How did you manage to work around this limitation? Please share.

Comment: As I mentioned before, it's still open, but now we have a ticket, probably I will work on this, but I can not work on this right now